# Flutter pagination issue. on list.builder scroll pagination not working

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Flutter, I get so much data in the ListView.builder. The scrollcontroller has been used.
I am trying to scroll, but all data fit within the visible screen so I can not scroll thats why Pagination is not happening.

But if I apply more margin top and bottom and all loaded data not fit in visible screen size only then scroll and pagination is worked.

Please check below code and screen shot

[image]

```
  final scrollController = ScrollController();

  int page = 1;
  bool isLoadMoreRunning = false;
  bool isMoreDataAvail = true;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchUserData();
    scrollController.addListener(_scrollListner);
  }

  Future<void> _scrollListner() async {
    if (isLoadMoreRunning) return;
    if (scrollController.position.pixels ==
        scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      setState(() {
        isLoadMoreRunning = true;
      });
      page++;
      await fetchUserData();
      setState(() {
        isLoadMoreRunning = false;
      });
    }
  }


  fetchUserData() async {
    List<BookingFromJobList> tempList = [];
    var token = PreferenceUtils.getString(PreferenceUtils.ACCESS_TOKEN, "");
    var driverId = PreferenceUtils.getString(PreferenceUtils.USER_ID, "");

    Map map = {
      'token': token,
      'status': "1",
      'page': page.toString(),
      'driver_id': driverId
    };
    print("page: $page");

    response = await BaseClient()
        .getBookingApi(context, 'application/booking/get', map);

    print("response: $response");
    late List<BookingFromJobList>? lstNotification;

    if(response == "NoData" || response == "error") {
      lstNotification = List.empty();
    }
    else{
      lstNotification = bookingModelFromJson(response).bookings;
    }

    if (lstNotification!.length == 0) {
      isMoreDataAvail = false;
    } else {
      isMoreDataAvail = true;
    }

    setState(() {
      notificationList.addAll(lstNotification!);
      print("response length: ${notificationList.length}");
      _isLoaded = true;
    });
  }


  Widget ListRecordWithLoader() {
    if (!_isLoaded) {
      return new Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else if (notificationList.length == 0) {
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          "No Job Available.",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return ListView.builder(
        controller: scrollController,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        itemCount: notificationList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => JobDetailsScreen(
                    jobID: notificationList[index].id.toString(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 15),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    blurRadius: 3,
                    offset: Offset(0, 0), // Shadow position
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0xfffce8ef),
                      border: Border.all(color: Color(0xfffce8ef), width: 1),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.notifications_active_outlined,
                        color: Color(0xfff2426d),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          RichText(
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            text: TextSpan(
                              // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                              // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              children: <TextSpan>[
                                TextSpan(
                                    text: "Job",
                                    //'${notificationList[index].nameOfJob}',
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                TextSpan(text: ' Assign Job For Pickup'),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          RichText(
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            text: TextSpan(
                              // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                              // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              children: <TextSpan>[
                                TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      '${notificationList[index].fromAddressObj!.shortAddress}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.blue),
                                ),
                                TextSpan(text: ' To Pickup '),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text:
                                      '${notificationList[index].toAddressObj!.shortAddress}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.blue),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to scroll when the data fits on your screen
you will only be able to scroll when all the `Listview` items don't fit the screen

Comment: Then How can I set pagination without scrolling?